# Powershell get-acl and set-acl for a whole network device after data migration

Tags: powershell, filesystems, acl, windows-server

**Case:**
we have to migrate a full storage to a new machine (both bare metal), Windows Server 2008 to Windows Server 2012 and do a cross-domain migration simultaneously.

Network Device 1 mounted with old domain administrator on Y: from old machine
Network Device 2 mounted with new domain administrator on Z: on new machine

We've successfully copied all data via Robocopy:

```
ROBOCOPY %SORC% %DEST% /MIR /DCOPY:T /B /R:1 /W:1 /NP /LOG:%LOG%
```

**Actual:**
Now we have to do two more steps: migrate the old user acl to the copied files and folders.
I've found get-acl and set-acl but with:

```
get-acl Y:\ | set-acl Z:\
```

it's only take action on that folder/file. For example if I run *get-acl 'Y:\IT\folder' | set-acl 'Z:\IT\folder'* the ACL on that single folder is copied successful.

**Problem**
a) How can I copy the ACL of every file and folder of the whole network device (old) to the new one with all files copied on that and
b) How do I deal with those files the old administrator on the old machine has no owner rights due to security setting errors in the past?

Hint: I've already tried /SEC Attribute on Robocopy and other Robocopy switches - it didn't work in our case due to we have to run the PS Script on the new domains storage with the new domain administrator - on the old storage is only powershell version 1 - because it's a server from 2008..

Answer (score 1):

Might need to do it file by file.  You can do this by getting a full recursive file list of all the folders & files on the original drive, and then loop through setting the ACL for each of them.  Something like:

```
gci -Recurse Y:\ | % {
    $ThisACL = Get-Acl $_.FullName
    $ThisACL | Set-Acl $_.FullName.Replace('Y:\','Z:\')
}
```

Of course, this would allow you to insert some "Write-Progress" statements to let it display to the screen so you can see how long it is taking.  Lots of additions you could make to improve feedback as it is running.

BTW, this is a totally untested first crack at the problem, so I would try this on a small subset before running it on your live data.  YMMV, no rights reserved. Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you have a hint to log those errors instead of printing them to the console? Here is for example a font file namend apple][.ttf ... why ever this is named so.............

Get-Acl : Das angegebene Platzhalterzeichenmuster ist ungültig: Apple ][.ttf
In C:\\Rechteuebernehmen.ps1:3 Zeichen:16
+     $ThisACL = Get-Acl $_.FullName
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Acl], WildcardPatternException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand

Comment: Many special characters cause PowerShell to try to do substitutions in paths, and the square brackets have caused me problems in the past.  LiteralPath allows you to specify a path exactly without any substitutions.  I my solution above, since we are sending each and every path indiividually, you can change to `Get-Acl -LiteralPath $_.FullName` and the same in the Set-Acl.  Warning: LiteralPath will not accept wildcards. Check this out: [Why you should always use LiteralPath](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/2wmzv8/why_you_should_consider_always_using_literalpath/)

Comment: As for logging errors, try using `Start-Transcript TranscriptFileName` before the code and `Stop-Transcript` after.  You'll get everything that was printed to the screen in the Transcript file.